# Typescript destructure values AND types from an import

Tags: typescript

In my application, I have a single file that imports and provides access to external dependencies called "dependencies.ts" for the purposes of bundle segmentation.

*dependencies.ts*

```js
export * as SomeDep from "some-dep"
export * as OtherDep from "other-dep"
```

I want to be able to destructure these imports so that I don't have to refer to them by their fully qualified name without expanding them in dependencies.ts.

*source.ts*

```js
import {SomeDep, OtherDep} from './dependencies'

// This works for concrete values, but not interfaces and other ephemeral types
const {
   NiftyClass,
   NiftyInterface /* <-- This would throw an error */
} = SomeDep

// This works, but would is extremely verbose.
type NiftyInterface = SomeDep.NiftyInterface
```

Is there some simple syntax for destructuring values AND types out of an import?

Comment: Have you tried `import {{NiftyClass, NiftyInterface}, OtherDep} from "./dependencies"`?

Comment: ES6 imports do not support destructuring, so I do not believe that would work